# Need solution for work File component for every activity

Tags: java, android

I have problem with using File component.

This code get list of inside of it's content.

```
java.io.File fileDir = new java.io.File("/sdcard/Android/data/com.byCM7.T3D.PR/", "Packs/");
final String[] listItems = fileDir.list();
Arrays.sort(listItems);
List<String> ListOfPacksInFolder = Arrays.asList(listItems);
```

Like this:
(Folder)Hello
(Image)Hello.png
(Sound)Hello.wav

In MainActivity, it gives me 2 (Originally 2)
But in second activity MainmenuActivity, it gives me 0 (Originally 2)

Is there a solution for work this code for every activity?
(I actually tried to add `MainmenuActivity,this`, but it gives me compile error)

I am new to those Android-java world, please help me!

Comment: It should work in every activity. And give the same result.

Comment: `new java.io.File("/sdcard/Android/data/com.byCM7.T3D.PR/", "Packs/");` That is pretty bad code with that hard coded path. You should use something like `new java.io.File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "Packs");` instead.